# How do you get the ScoreDirectorFactory from a previous solution in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have a previously solved solution in OptaPlanner and I want to retrieve the ScoreDirectorFactory from that solution without running the solver. Is it achievable through the current API?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```java
MyPlanningSolution mpe = getMySolution();
SolverFactory<MyPlanningSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(CONFIG);
Solver<MyPlanningSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
solver.setSolution(mpe);
ScoreDirectorFactory factory = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory();
```

I succeeded into getting the ScoreDirectorFactory by pinning all my planning entities and setting the termination to 0 seconds. It seems like a detour to me since I have to start the solver for nothing. Is there another way?

Comment: You don't have to start the solver (no `solve()` call), but you're right - this is an API gap. Please create a jira at issues.jboss.org and set it as blocked by https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1630.

Comment: Alright, I'll do. However, I think that the solve call is still necessary since that is where you provide the Planning solution. Ex.
`
SolverFactory<Schedule> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(NO_MOVE_CONFIGURATION);
        Solver<Schedule> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
        schedule.getScheduleTimes().forEach(scheduleTime -> scheduleTime.isPinned(true));
        solver.solve(schedule);
        setSolverExplanation(solver.getScoreDirectorFactory());`

Comment: In the UI you want to react on bestSolution events, which include the bestSolution (= planning clone of the working solution). That bestSolution is what you want to explain to the UI (via indictments etc). It is already solved at that point. That it comes from a Solver is irrelevant. It must use its own ScoreDirector. It has it's own Solution instance because that bestSolution isn't the working solution. There's no reason to tie this into the Solver, AFAIK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1686

We're adding `SolverFactory.getScoreDirectorFactory()` and deprecating `Solver.getScoreDirectorFactory()`.